# How can I select the next reservation Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table calles reservation and it contains all reservation for every vehicle.
and I have a reservationStatus field which mean 1 = scheduled 2= pending, 0=canceled.

So I want to select the next reservation date from the table based on the current pending record.

So when i run this code

```
SELECT dateFrom, dateTo FROM reservation WHERE reservationStatus = 2
```

that will give me the current pending reservation. Now from here I want to return the very first record where `dateFrom` field is less than or equal to the previous `dateTo`?

can this be done in one select statement? I know it can be done using 2 separate statement with some php but I was wondering if it can be written in MySql in one query?

**EDIT - New bit added to the question**

This is how I would solve it with 2 queries and some PHP.

```
$sql = $db->query('SELECT dateTo FROM reservation WHERE Vehicle_id='. $id . ' AND reservationStatus = 2 LIMIT 1 ');
$first = $sql->fetch_assoc();
$sql->free();
$sql = $db->query('SELECT dateFrom FROM reservation WHERE Vehicle_id='. $id . ' AND reservationStatus = 1 AND (dateFrom > \''.$first['dateTo'] .'\') ORDER BY dateFrom ASC ');

$row = $sql->fetch_assoc();

$month = strtotime($first['dateTo']);
$end = strtotime($row['dateFrom']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT dateFrom, dateTo FROM reservation WHERE reservationStatus = 2
ORDER BY dateFome DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Will order the results by `dateFrom` (newest first) and just fetch the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Use order by with datefrome,and limit 1.
This will give the result you required

```
SELECT dateFrom, dateTo reservation WHERE reservationStatus = 2
ORDER BY dateFome DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT dateFrom, dateTo FROM reservation WHERE reservationStatus = 2 
ORDER BY dateFrom DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think I miss-explaining the problem. Please check my post again as i added a solution with 2 separate queries. I just want to make it better into one query.